# Training and testing accuracy coming same

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, deep-learning

I am building a model which will classify the data into 7.

The input comprises of 7 bands which are extracted from GIS dataset. I am taking one pixel of a band and then using supervised classification method training my neural network.

There are 2 issues:

- the first one being that my training accuracy is same through every epochs
- the second one that training and testing accuracy are also same in each epochs.

I have tried changing various models, optimizers and activation function.

**Code**

```
from keras.layers import Dense,Input,Dropout
from keras.models import Model
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import scipy.io as sci
import time

mat=sci.loadmat('landsat/dataset_beta.mat')
X1=mat.get('x')
Y1=mat.get('y')
X1, Y1 = shuffle(X1, Y1)

m=int(85*X1.shape[0]/100)
bands=7
print(m)

X_train=X1[0:m,0:bands]
Y_train=Y1[0:m]
X_test=X1[m:X1.shape[0],0:bands]
Y_test=Y1[m:X1.shape[0]]


print('Total training examples: '+str(X_train.shape[0]))
print('Total test examples: '+str(X_test.shape[0]))
print('X_train dimensions: '+str(X_train.shape))
print('Y_train dimensions: '+str(Y_train.shape))
print('X_test dimensions: '+str(X_test.shape))
print('Y_test dimensions: '+str(Y_test.shape))

inp=Input(shape=(bands,))
layer=Dense(11,activation='sigmoid')(inp)
#layer=Dropout(0.2)(layer)
layer=Dense(22,activation='sigmoid')(layer)
layer=Dense(33,activation='sigmoid')(layer)
layer=Dense(44,activation='sigmoid')(layer)
layer=Dense(55,activation='sigmoid')(layer)
layer=Dense(66,activation='sigmoid')(layer)
layer=Dense(77,activation='sigmoid')(layer)
layer=Dense(88,activation='sigmoid')(layer)
layer=Dense(99,activation='sigmoid')(layer)
layer=Dense(110,activation='sigmoid')(layer)
layer=Dense(110,activation='sigmoid')(layer)
layer=Dense(99,activation='sigmoid')(layer)
layer=Dense(88,activation='sigmoid')(layer)
layer=Dense(77,activation='sigmoid')(layer)
layer=Dense(66,activation='sigmoid')(layer)
layer=Dense(55,activation='sigmoid')(layer)
layer=Dense(44,activation='sigmoid')(layer)
layer=Dense(33,activation='sigmoid')(layer)
layer=Dense(22,activation='sigmoid')(layer)
layer=Dense(11,activation='sigmoid')(layer)
layer=Dense(7,activation='softmax')(layer)
model=Model(inputs=inp,outputs=layer)

model.compile('RMSprop','binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

history=model.fit(X_train,Y_train,epochs=50,steps_per_epoch=20,validation_data=(X_test,Y_test),validation_steps=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model is very deep without batch normalization or other deep learning techniques to handle deep networks.

Start with a model with less layers to check if the code is working. Then you can try deeper models.

Answer (score 0):

Issue:
The problem with your network is depth. Main problem might be vanishing gradient descent. ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanishing_gradient_problem )

Things to keep in mind before opting for a deep model.
1. Why not a traditional machine learning model ?
2. Do you have enough data to train a deep model ? If not can you do transfer learning?
3. Are there any models trained on similar kind of tasks ?

when I started learning deep learning I used to experiment with more hidden layers. But most of the models didn't converge. According to me the best way is to implement the well known models ( vgg ) and try to play with the hyperparameters.
Also Keras has lots of pre-trained models, you can fine tune the pre-trained models.

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel said above, it's a good habit to use common DL techniques like batch normalization. These will help with your dataset and therefore training. The aforementioned batch normalization, for example, helps make the dataset much more "simple", to put it simply.

I wrote about these different Deep Learning model techniques (batch norm, data reshuffling, dropout, etc) in a beginner Deep Learning guide I wrote, you can check it out [here](https://www.energize.ai/stockprediction/).

Good Luck & let me know if you have questions!

Comment: I have reduced the model and verified data once again. Tried using batch normalisation but the result is validation accuracy is still not changing. While the training accuracy seems to move between 0.85 -0.86. It is not going above 0.86 while loss and validation loss are constantly improving.

Comment: inp=Input(shape=(121,))

layer=Dense(82)(inp)
layer=BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(layer)
layer=Activation('relu')(layer)
layer=Dropout(0.3)(layer)

layer=Dense(54)(layer)
layer=BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(layer)
layer=Activation('relu')(layer)
layer=Dropout(0.3)(layer)




layer=Dense(2)(layer)
layer=Activation('softmax')(layer)


model=Model(inputs=inp,outputs=layer,name='Classifier')